# Python: What is the Best way to split a string of 9 characters into 3 characters each and join them using delimiters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string "111222333" inside a CSV file.  I would like to convert this into something like "\111\222\333"

Currently my python code is :

```
refcode = "111222333"
returnstring = "\\" + refcode[:3] + "\\" + refcode[3:6] + "\\" + refcode[-3:] + "\\"
```

I know there must be a better way to do this.  May I know what are the better ways to do the same thing.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` for that:

```
import re
refcode = "111222333"

returnstring = '\\'.join(re.match('()(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})()', refcode).groups())
```

Explanation:
You have a string of 9 characters (let's say they are not any kind of whitespace chatacters, so we could represent it with `\S`).
We create a matching regexp using it, so `(\S{3})` is a group of three sequential non-space characters (like letters, numbers, exclamation marks etc.).

`(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})` are three groups with 3 characters in each one.

If we call `.groups()` on it, we'll have a tuple of the matched groups, just like that:

```
In [1]: re.match('(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})', refcode).groups()
Out[1]: ('111', '222', '333')
```

If we join it using a `\` string, we'll get a:

```
In [29]: print "\\".join(re.match('(\S{3})(\S{3})(\S{3})', refcode).groups())
111\222\333
```

But you want to add the backslashes on the both sides of the string as well!
So we could create an empty group - `()` - on the each side of the regular expression.